# How can I get a transparent Bootstrap navbar in the WordPress header.php with an image underneath?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a code layout question for Bootstrap and WordPress. So basically I want to accomplish this Bootstrap transparent nav look but inside the WordPress template hierarchy structure..

[image: Screenshot]

Header.php contains the navigation that every page will have in a WordPress theme. Right now to get this look, I have the Bootstrap jumbotron class div wrapped around the nav which works great for a regular website.

The **issue** is that I don't think this will work in WordPress because the nav code will need to be separate in the header.php file and the jumbotron image only needs to be on the homepage. **Any suggestions on how I can do this?**

```css
.jumbotron {
position: relative;
background: url("http://kriswhitewrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/landscape-mountains-snow-sky.jpg") center center;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
min-height: 550px;
overflow: hidden;
}



  .navbar {
      background-color: transparent;
      background: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-customnav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-custom">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>


          <div class="container">
              <h3>Search for jobs</h3>
          </div>
        </div><!--End of Jumbotron-->
```

Comment: I don't understand You. You wish nav without background transparent color ?

Comment: Panda, no matter what you libraries or frameworks you use, they still all output `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript`. That's why and how the web works. Also, as a side note, Bootstrap and WordPress are not incompatible. *Au contraire*...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sigh I must have not been clear at all. I know Bootstrap can work within WordPress. I've built themes before with Bootstrap. 

The question is the jumbrotron class div is wrapped around the navbar. Usually for header.php you don't put the homepage billboard image in the navigation links. So I was looking for another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello PandaNinja (awesome name, btw).

It sounds like that you're trying to put a Jumbotron Bootstrap-template on your Wordpress-site. That is do-able, but it requires a few steps (and it varies from template to template, what needs to be done (since different Wordpress-templates handles the navigation 'and stuff' differently. For instance, - here is the code from Wordpress Twenty-Fourteen navigation (taken from the `header.php`-file, in this path: /wp-content/themes/twenty-fourteen/header.php):

```
<div class="header-main">
 <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
  <div class="search-toggle">
   <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="search-container"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
  </div>
 <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
   <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></button>
   <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
 </nav>
</div>
```

In this case, then you're able to add some classes and ID's to the different part of that code, so it is shown on the page.

So it you edit your post, with how it looks on your site now and post your code and which template you use, then it's easier to help.

As Andrei said in the comments, - then when Wordpress (and PHP) and done doing their part, then everything is outputted as HTML, CSS and JavaScript in the end.

**Edit1 - Addition (answer to comment)**

There are many ways to do it. You can both make that gradient with pure CSS, but I think if it was me, then I would just use an image, like I've done here: https://jsfiddle.net/5xhv1sLt/3/
You can download the image I've used here (right-click the link and choose 'save target as...'): http://imgh.us/bgrepeat.png

It's not the prettiest thing in the world - but it shows the idea.

Now - the challenge is to get it into your Wordpress-theme. There's two ways to do it:

1) To see what styles that your current Wordpress-theme puts on the navigation, and then tweak and tune that, to make it do what you want. You can perhaps copy the code from the source-code into your question, - then I can help you get the styles right.

2) To go into the header.php-file in your theme, remove the line that most likely looks like this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

... And then accept that you can't control the Wordpress menu, from the 'Appearence >> Menu'-section in your Wordpress dashboard. And then insert your own manually-written navigation (with the proper format).

I don't know what I would recommend you, since it depends on, how often things change and who has to control the site. For instance - if it was my mother who had to use the website, then I would probably go for option 1, - but if it was my own online resume website (that changes once every 2nd year), then I would go for option 2.

:-)

Comment: Hi Warden. Thank you for the compliment. So add an ID to the jumbotron div class so it only shows up on the WordPress theme homepage? Can you show me an example?

I basically wrote the jumbotron background image div to wrap around the transparent navbar so the image displays underneath the nav because the code is nested. If I put the navbar separately above the jumbotron there is this ugly space and a gap above the background image.

Comment: Ask, and you shall receive. :-) ... I've done it in an addition in my answer.

Comment: Uhh... And remember to make the Fiddle-window wider, since it'll collapse the navigation, if it's too narrow (making it responsive, so it folds out).

Comment: Did you see my answer? And does it fit what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you Warden I see the addition to your answer. Than you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to make it so that the header which you refer to as `.navbar` in the code looks different **only** in the homepage of your wordpress website.

First of all you don't need to add any specific style to the `header.php` file, you can use the `style.css` file.

To do so you just need to use a functionality that is provided by Wordpress.

Basically Wordpress adds a custom `class` to the `body` of each page it outputs.

As such in order for you to select the navigation and style it differently only in the homepage you can use the following selector:

```
body.home .navbar
```

Please note that wordpress outputs various classes for different pages, so using various `body.specificPageClass` will be helpful in writing elegant and non redundant css.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The question is more so code management. The jumbrotron class div has a background image and is wrapped around the navbar so that the image and transparent nav show up together and nested rather than the nav on top of the background cover size image. Usually for header.php you don't put the homepage billboard image in the navigation links. So I was looking for another way or wondering if this will work.

The homepage is the only one that will have the billboard image. The conflict is putting the navigation code nested inside jumbotron

Comment: Can you show me an example using body.home .navbar?